# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Collections.Immutable'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, microsoft-code-analysis

I'm running a dot net core 6 api project where i use the roslyn library Microsoft.CodeAnalysis to format some text to C# code.
in local test everyting work perfectly, but when i publish on IIS, the function that uses the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis returns this error
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Collections.Immutable, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

i use these librairies:

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Formatting;
```

all of them version 4.0.6
i follwed some online threads that suggested to downgrade the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis to 4.0.2 or 4.0.0, i did that and the problem persists.
what i'm i missing.
thanks :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, but what about adding a reference to System.Collections?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60757594/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-collections-immutable-but-i-dont-have) .

Comment: @Mahobo already tried that , same error.

Comment: @QingGuo, i looked up that thread, also diden't work for me.

Comment: did you try publishing your project as single file? That helped me bringing my WPF to live in WinPE environment